# Can I use a stereo cable extensor for a mono microphone

Tags: stereo, cable, mono

I just got small microphone to use with my mobile phone. The microphone has no cable, just the 3.5mm jack, but I need some leeway to move the microphone away from my device. I was looking up for extension cables but I only see stereo extensor cables available (I don't live in the US). The microphone jack has only one ring, so I assume it is a mono microphone. My question is: can I use a stereo cable extensor to extend my microphone or do I have to use a mono extensor cable? Also, if it is actually possible to use the stereo cable, do I need to use an adapter or can I simply plug it in directly?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a stereo extension cable. When you use a stereo cable with a mono microphone, the second channel will be unused. No adapter needed.

Comment: Thanks so much Hobbes!